# Dynamic Changing of Chart Type (Bar to Line as Example) in in Chart.js with PHP and MySQL

Tags: chart.js

Greetings of tranquility and greatness, I hope you have a wonderful day. I would like to ask what code should  I need to include in order to make my code dynamic in response to the dropdown button that is chosen. For instance, I choose bar, thus the graph ought to be bar; but, when I pick line, the graph should be line. Thank you! (However it should be conected to mysql and php)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    showGraph();
});

const showGraph = () => {
    {
        $.post("assets/include/data.php",function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            var name = [];
            var marks = [];

            for (var i in data) {
                name.push(data[i].LEVEL);
                marks.push(data[i].TOTAL);
            }

            var chartdata1 = {
                labels: name,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Grade Level',
                        backgroundColor: ['#88D969', '#46CB1B', '#06A10B', '#1D800E'],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: '#FCA510',
                        data: marks,
                        barPercentage: 1.0,
                        categoryPercentage: 1.0
                        
                    }
                ],
            };

            var graphTarget = $("#graph");

            var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata1,
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            grid: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        },
                        x: {
                            grid: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    responsive: true
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, of course, you have to add event listeners to run some code when you click on a dropdown item. In your event handlers, a safe strategy with Chart.js is to **destroy** the chart and immediately create another one with a new configuration object. Here is an example:

```js
function config(type) {
  return {
    type,
    data: {
      labels: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset',
        data: [10, 20, 15]
      }]
    }
  }
}

function init(type) {
  return new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), config(type));
}

let chart = init('bar');

document.querySelector('#bar').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chart.destroy();
  chart = init('bar');
});

document.querySelector('#line').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chart.destroy();
  chart = init('line');
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css";

.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-i9cEfJwUwViEPFKdC1enz4ZRGBj8YQo6QByFTF92YXHi7waCqyexvRD75S5NVTsSiTv7rKWqG9Y5eFxmRsOn0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle mt-3 mb-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown button
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><button id="bar" class="dropdown-item" type="button">Bar</button></li>
          <li><button id="line" class="dropdown-item" type="button">Line</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```